# How to get a full url using reverse in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to save in a variable the url to access a service, so I am using `reverse` and the `name` for the entry in `urlpatterns`, and I get something like `/es/general/provider_types/`, but I want to get a full url, like `https://127.0.0.1:8000/es/general/provider_types/`

This is how I am using `reverse`:

```
{'name': models.ProviderType._meta.verbose_name_plural.title(), 'url': reverse('rest_provider_types_list')}
```

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Does this code located inside view?

Comment: No, it's in a function called from a view, but not in the view.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`request.build_absolute_uri()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri) method which return absolute url:

```
request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('rest_provider_types_list'))
```